# latex \listoffigures and \listoftables numbers overlap caption

Tags: latex, overlap, spacing

when using \listoffigues and \listoftables the numbers and the captions overlap each other. For example: "2-10 laminar flow" --> 10 and lam overlap each other.

I'd like to add horizontal space without changing the format.
I tried "\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{6em}}" already. The horizontal space is fine now, but this command added vertical space between the lines which I don't want. 
The tocloft package changes the entire format so I don't want to use it.

Any ideas how to change the horizontal space between numbers and caption only?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ Would probably be more helpful since it's specific to LaTeX.

Comment: @Quotidian: Your comment just suggests to the new user to cross-post on a different network. Rather flag this for moderator attention and suggest migration to [tex.se]. Alternatively, vote-to-close. No need to suggest posting elsewhere, as migration naturally follows.